# Changing string in variable from array in C

Tags: c

Is there any way to make this, I have an array of strings which are divided with spacebar like : sth1 sth2 sth3 sth4

And I would like to use firstly sth1 in `strncmp` and secondly sth2 in `strncmp`

Comment: Yes, there is a way: learn about `strtok` - and you've already solved half of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is getting the strings. For which you can use `strtok`.

A small demo would be something like this:

suppose the line contains the strings separated by spaces.(in `line`)

```
char *word;
word=strtok(line," ");
char list[N1][N2];
int index =0;
while(word != NULL)
{
    print("%s \n", word); // you can also copy this.
    memset(list[index], '\0', sizeof(list[index]));
    strncpy(list[index++],word,strlen(word));
    word=strtok(NULL," ");
}

if( strncmp(list[0],list[1],BUFFERSIZE))
{
  //...
}
```

Based on OP's comment I understand that OP wants to read words in a single char array and then compare each of the words with another word.

As we are tokenizing the string in `list[]`..we can use this to compare with other word.

Comment: @Donatoris.: 42 dimensional array? It is not needed I guess

Comment: my problem is that i use `char array[101]={0};
while(scanf("%100s", array) != EOF)` it has around 50 words, and then i need to use `strncmp`to compare each with this string `scanf("%13s",str);`

Comment: @Donatoris.: I will come back to this answer to help you within some hour

Comment: @Donatoris>: Mdified the answer...I guess you get it now

Comment: im so sorry but still dont know how to do it, pls can you modify the code ?

Comment: You are getting words in a line. But you need to divide it into words. So you are doing that using `strtok`..Google strtok and you will see how it is used.

Comment: @Donatoris.: Tell me the problem statement I guess you didn't understand. (As it was given)